# El insert que utilizo para cargar los usuarios funciona en el localhost y en otros apartados del sitio pero no en el host

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Este codigo es el que esta dando problemas a la hora de cargar los usuario en la tabla, utilizando el host de xampp funciona correctamente pero en 000webhost no carga los usuarios.

```
<?php   
include("conexion.php");
if (!$conexion) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion';
    }else{
        echo 'Conectado a la base de datos <br>';
    }
//para prevenir mysql injection
$nombre= mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombre']);
$apellido=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['apellido']);
$nombreusuario=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['nombreusuario']);
$email=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['email']);
$password=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['password']);



            if (empty($_POST['nombreusuario'] && $_POST['password'])) {
                echo "El nombre o la contraseña están vacíos";
            }else{
            //insertar usuario en la base de datos
                $password=md5($_POST['password']);
                $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellido,nombreusuario,email,password,telefono,direccion,nacionalidad,fechanac,dni,rango) VALUES ('$_POST[nombre]','$_POST[apellido]','$_POST[nombreusuario]','$_POST[email]','$password','','','','','','')";
                //  var_dump($sql_insert);die;
                mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_insert);
                if (!$sql_insert) {
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Error al registrarse, intente nuevamente");
                    window.location.href="../index.php#login";
                    </script>';
                }else{
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Usuario registrado correctamente, ya puede iniciar");
                    window.location.href="../index.php";
                    </script>';
                }
                //Cerrar conexion
                mysqli_close($conexion);
            }
```

?> Este codigo en cambio si funciona en el localhost y en el host, por lo que no se si el problema se encuentra en la tabla de usuarios o  directamente en la carga de usuarios del codigo anterior, es probable que sea un error muy facil de solucionar pero al no saber muy bien que es lo que estoy haciendo y segun la documentacion deberia de estar bien.
Si alguien encuentra la solucion estaria muy agradecido.

```
<?php   
include("conexion.php");
session_start();
//var_dump($_SESSION['id']);die;
$idusuario=$_SESSION['id'];
if (!$conexion) {
        echo 'Error en la conexion';
    }else{
        echo 'Conectado a la base de datos <br>';
    }

    $archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    
    if (isset($archivo) && $archivo != "") {
       
       $tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
       $tamano = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
       $temp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
       
      if (!((strpos($tipo, "gif") || strpos($tipo, "jpeg") || strpos($tipo, "jpg") || strpos($tipo, "png")) && ($tamano < 2000000))) {
         echo '<div><b>Error. La extensión o el tamaño de los archivos no es correcta.<br/>
         - Se permiten archivos .gif, .jpg, .png. y de 200 kb como máximo.</b></div>';
      }
      else {

         if (move_uploaded_file($temp, 'img/'.$archivo)) {
            
             chmod('img/'.$archivo, 0777);

         }
         else {
            //Si no se ha podido subir la imagen, mostramos un mensaje de error
            echo '<div><b>Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.</b></div>';
         }
       }
    }


//para prevenir mysql injection
$empresa= mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['empresa']);
$puesto=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['puesto']);
$jornada=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['jornada']);
$salario= mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['salario']);
$zona=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['zona']);
$observaciones=  mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['observaciones']);

                
                $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO empleos(empresa,puesto,jornada,salario,zona,observaciones,imagen, usuarioid) 
                VALUES ('$_POST[empresa]','$_POST[puesto]','$_POST[jornada]','$_POST[salario]','$_POST[zona]','$_POST[observaciones]','$archivo', '$idusuario')";
        //  var_dump($sql_insert);die;
            mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_insert);
                if (!$sql_insert) {
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Hubo un error al cargar el empleo, comprueba que los datos sean correctos");
                    window.location.href="../php/empleos.php";
                    </script>';
                }else{
                    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location.href="../php/empleos.php";
                    </script>';
                }
                //Cerrar conexion
                mysqli_close($conexion);
```

?>

Comment: Y has comprobado que por consola puedes realizar una query correctamente usando los datos de tu php?

Comment: @Benito-B no tengo idea de como hacer eso, voy a buscar en internet y en un rato te lo confirmo

Comment: Estás escapando los datos, pero en la consulta usas las variables originales de `$_POST`.

Comment: @Triby No creo que sea eso porque deberia de cargar los datos sin escapar igual, pero gracias, no me habia dado cuenta de eso

Answer (score 0):

Verifique el nombre de la base de datos en 000webhost , en algunos casos le añaden prefijos a las DB, verifique que el usuario y contraseña del usuario de DB creado en 000webhost es correcto, antes de testear el INSERT desde el phpmyadmin o consola de mysql haga un SELECT para saber si sí hay comunicación, verifique que la versión de php y de la DB es igual o mayor al que tiene instalado en xampp.

Comment: Eso funciona bien, los usuario que ya estan registrados pueden iniciar sesion con exito. Tambien puedo agregar empleos a la tabla de empleos